# Magnetic hysteresis BH curve to compare "Fe-Ni" "Fe-Si"

Tags: magnetics, hysteresis

I am compiling some training material and would like to include a graph to indicate the different characteristics of silicon steel "Fe-Si" and mumetal "Fe-Ni".  The best curve I could find in SI units below seems theoretical.

Does anyone have a better graph that can be used?

[image]

Comment: Better in what respect?

Comment: You should demonstrate the curves before it saturates too showing that is more of a continuous cloud that starts as an oval and gets larger and squeezed into the S-shaped box as you crank up the current

Comment: better for what. there are hundreds of different types of silicon steel profiles ,, search CRGOS

Comment: I only need more realistic curves, both on the same axis and SI units.  Only the outer curve will do.